# Flash, LocalConnection and DOM

Tags: flash, dom, localconnection

I have a Flash object on my site, which has this code:

```
this.ld = new LocalConnection();
this.ld.allowDomain("*");
ExternalInterface.call("alert", this.ld.domain);
```

It alerts my domain successfully. However, what I want is to access the HTML DOM through this using LocalConnection and not ExternalInterface directly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ExternalInterface`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) is your best bet in accessing HTML DOM. `LocalConnection` is for communication between different SWF files within the same page/browser.

> The [LocalConnection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) class lets you create a LocalConnection object that can invoke a method in another `LocalConnection` object, either within a single `SWF` file or between multiple `SWF` files.